# Assistance with my class assignment

Tags: variable-assignment

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Problem Statement
As outlined in the background story, you are in the middle of a shark-infested
ocean. The sandbank along which you may travel is very narrow (only wide
enough to walk in a straight line with a little room to make turns) and is
bordered by electric wire along the edges i.e. if you touch off the wire, you will be electrocuted and fall into the ocean – a state from which there is no return.

The years in prison have taken their toll both physically and mentally. Due to
adverse sleeping conditions, sensory deprivation and regular beatings, your
senses are poor and movements now restricted to taking 1 exact same step
at a time in a forwards direction (i.e. the direction in which you are facing).
Also, you are no longer able to turn left and turning to the right can only be
done 90 degrees at a time. 2.) the only data you are able to store in your
memory is limited to a single integer value (it may be possible to scrounge up
some space to store a boolean value, though you're unlikely to need this).

Luckily, you can still do the basic arithmetic operations of addition and
subtraction. To aid your decision-making and control of repetitive actions you
know about an IF statement and WHILE loop. You also recognise a true or
false response to a question and can test the values of integers using any of
the operators <, >, ≤ and ≥. Of course, you also know about the interger
values 0, 1, 2 etc.. Unfortunately, logical operations are beyond your current
processing power. Any further assumptions should be confirmed by the tutor.

In a rare display of compassion HAL has permitted that you be allowed ask 3
questions, to which you will receive a true or false response: “in front of
gate?”, “in front of wire?” and “in front of sand?”. You may also ask the
complement of these questions i.e. “not in front of gate?”, “not in front of
wire?” and “not in front of sand?”. There is no restriction on how many times
you may ask these questions and these states cannot exist at the same time.

[image]

Basically I need a short algorithm to get from gate 1 to gate 2. I've been at it for hours and can't seem to do it and it's due for today. Please please help thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
While (not in front of gate)
  int right_count = 0
  While (not in front of sand)
    Turn right
    right_count++
    If right_count == 2
      Turn right
  Step forward
Step forward // party time
```

Edit: I'd be interested in seeing some of your attempts

Comment: I bet there are no attempts. ;-)

Comment: In hind sight I should have asked for that first

Comment: @ParrisVarney I already had an algorithm like this one but it doesn't work because you will get to a point where you will just turn around 180 degrees and go back the way you came.

Comment: I was wondering what all that variable assignment stuff was for, good catch, I've edited my answer